# display wordpress posts in a non-wordpress external site

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have looked for almost every info available there but nothing worked for me. I want to show wordpress posts of some users on my website which is not on wordpress platform but hosted in MS Azure.Can someone guide me on this.? The wordpress website is free so i cant use plugin.

Comment: Have you tried looking into using the WordPress Rest API to pull your posts in remotely?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode : plugins menu not showing in my dashboard. (may be because my account is free).

Comment: The Rest API is part of WordPress core now, it's no longer a plugin. https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode thank you sir for the info..really helpful

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode post your answer and i will mark it correct!! thanks

Comment: No worries, done and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating this as an answer:

You can use WordPress Rest API now as it's part of WordPress core and doesn't require any 3rd party plugins.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/